# Outlook: When emails displaying swapped

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When logged into my outlook my to address is saying who the email is from and my from address is saying my email (to address).

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you aren't looking in your sent folder?  I've done it before.